# passing env. variables to downstream job after job failed

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I have a jenkins upstream job, which on failure will trigger the downstream job, but I need to pass the same env. variable of upstream job in the downstream job.

I am using powershell to set the env. variables like `$env:tag=$(git describe)` i.e generating my git tag. How can I send this env. variable in the downstream job, without using the git url in the downstream job.

And the downstream job should only get triggered on failure of upstream job.

I have used triggered parameterized build plugin by storing the env. variable in a txt file (`echo "$env:tag=$(git describe)" > env.txt`) but this also not working.

I have tried few other plugins but nothing working out.

usecase: JobA wants to pass its env. variable set in the powershell ($ENV:tag) to JobB. Therefore in the configuration of JobA the predefined parameters textfield is used to resolve the name but does not work as expected. Instead the whole string "$ENV:tag" is passed instead of "env-value". Here how I configured it:

– JobA-------

predefined parameters: gittag=$ENV:tag =>pass parameter on to JobB

– JobB--------

echo gittag =>output: echo $ENV:tag => $ENV:tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PASSING ENV. VARIABLES FROM UPSTREAM TO DOWNSTREAM JOB IN JENKINS

. write the variables needed from the upstream job to a property( IN OUR CASE 
  env.properties file) file in the downstream job's workspace.

```
echo Var1=value>../Downstream_Job_Folder/downstream.properties
echo Var2=value>>../Downstream_Job_Folder/downstream.properties

---------- IN MY CASE -------------
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
$commit_id=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
$tag=$(git describe)
echo var1=$commit_id > "C:\Program Files 
                        (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\powershell_2\env.properties"
echo var2=$tag >> "C:\Program Files 
                   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\powershell_2\env.properties" 
echo $commit_id
echo $tag       # TO CROSS-CHECK
```

. In the downstream job, use the EnvInject Plugin as your first build step, AND

```
- give Properties File Path - env.properties
```

. Then choose the second build step as windows powershell , and for windows powershell to 
  read the env.properties file , use below commands

```
- $AppProps = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content env.properties -raw)

  $AppProps.'var1'   # will print the var1 value

  $AppProps.'var2'   # will print the var2 value

  $env:commit_id=$AppProps.'var1'

  $env:tag=$AppProps.'var2'

  echo git:$env:tag      
  echo git:$env:commit_id   # this will print the desired output
```

----------In case of linux -------------------

. IN THE UPSTREAM JOB

```
- echo "name=@@" > /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/sh_tst_2/env.properties
- echo "age=22"  >> /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/sh_tst_2/env.properties
```

. In the downstream job, use the EnvInject Plugin as your first build step, AND

```
- give Properties File Path - env.properties
```

. Then choose the second build step as LINUX SHELL

- echo $name
- echo $age        # WILL GIVE U THE OUTPUT OF THE ENV. VAR FROM UPSTREAM JOB

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use Parameterized Trigger Plugin.
Here is the link for more details: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: already tried this plugin , as i mentioned in the question  , but its not working . i want to use the env. variables described in my jenkins powershell in downstream job .

Comment: You need to create a variable with same name in the downstream job also.

Comment: Have attached the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: i already tried this  and it is working for KEY=VALUE pair , but i want to use env. varibles used in my upstream job in downstream job and iam not able to do that .

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34911) with this plugin.

If the downstream job is only triggered when the upstream job fails, then do not make the downstream job a parameterized job.  Instead, write the variables needed from the upstream job to a property file in the downstream job's workspace.

```
echo Var1=value>../Downstream_Job_Folder/downstream.properties
echo Var2=value>>../Downstream_Job_Folder/downstream.properties
```

In the downstream job, use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) as your first build step, or write a script to read the vars from the file.

Comment: i am able to create the env.properties in the downstream job by running the upstream job as per your instructions , but for some reason it is not reading the env. variables . I tried "echo %var%" in windows batch command , "echo $env:var" in powershell but no output .

OUTPUT

[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.

[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'env.properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.


workspace\rollback>echo  
ECHO is on.

Comment: I am sure you did this, but just to verify, when you open the env.properties file in an editor you see the var and its value as expected (var_name=var value). And in the downstream job, the job log states that the vars where successfully injected, but in your next build step, an echo of the var is giving you a null value and not the value that was passed down. Is that correct?

Comment: yes you are correct , but why it is not taking the variables ?

Comment: I don't know.  It works in my Jenkins instance.  The only issue I have run into is if I try to make the value read in as if it is a var.  Example: instead of passing Var_1=%var_value% (which reads in the actual value), I do Var_1=$Another_Var.  In this case the $ gets escaped when imported and is read as a literal character in other steps.  Wish I could have offered more help.